# How to delete a row based on number of cells in this row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, data-manipulation, delete-row

I have a long data frame which contains some data for my project
I want to delete the row that contains more than 2 cells

here is my sample code

```
A         B           C          D          E          F
9012_1   :2683_1_0
9044_0   :2680_1_0
9007_1   9007_2      :8487_3_0   :8487_4_0  :2675_1_0
8814_2   :8374_1_2
77114_0  77114_1     :53453_1_0  :53453_1_1
```

I want my output to be like this

```
A         B           C          D          E          F
9012_1   :2683_1_0
9044_0   :2680_1_0

8814_2   :8374_1_2
```

how could it be done, as I have searched for it many times and could not find any answer.

Thanks

Comment: The empty cells are strings (`""`)? or NaNs?

Comment: I think the cells are NaNs

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I'm supposing you have this dataframe:

```
         A          B           C           D          E   F
0   9012_1  :2683_1_0         NaN         NaN        NaN NaN
1   9044_0  :2680_1_0         NaN         NaN        NaN NaN
2   9007_1     9007_2   :8487_3_0   :8487_4_0  :2675_1_0 NaN
3   8814_2  :8374_1_2         NaN         NaN        NaN NaN
4  77114_0    77114_1  :53453_1_0  :53453_1_1        NaN NaN
```

Then:

```
print(df[df.notna().sum(1) <= 2])
```

Prints:

```
        A          B    C    D    E   F
0  9012_1  :2683_1_0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
1  9044_0  :2680_1_0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
3  8814_2  :8374_1_2  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the same `df` as @Andrej.

You could use `count(axis=1)` which will count the non `nan` across columns, and use `~` operator with `gt(3)`. This will delete the rows that have more than 2 non `nan`.

```
print(df[~df.count(1).gt(3)])

        A          B    C    D    E   F
0  9012_1  :2683_1_0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
1  9044_0  :2680_1_0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
3  8814_2  :8374_1_2  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
```